# Plugins and plugin managers in VIM

Tags: vim

i'm new to Vim so i'm not really sure what i am doing:
i'd like to know how plugins and plugin managers work.

I read about many different plugin managers, and some of them contained also syntax highlighting and color schemes, but how do i download them?
Also, a plugin manager is used to download other plugins or it's just a "bundle" of plugins? And how do i download them?

Sorry if i sound dumb, but i'really just entered this world, and everything it's just confusing...

Comment: I'm not an expert on plugin managers, but since you're new to the vim world (welcome!) I have to give you links to these great video tutorials on vim: http://vimcasts.org/ and http://derekwyatt.org/vim/tutorials/index.html Also, I would highly recommend the book Practical Vim by Drew Neil. The README.md here https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug gives a good overview of the most popular(?) vim plugin manager. Good luck!

Comment: I’m voting to migrate this question to https://vi.stackexchange.com/ . At SO the Q is off-topic as it's not about programming or programming tools.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing "distributions", "plugins", and "plugin managers".

1. Plugins are collections of files organised in a standard way that you can add to your own "runtime", `$HOME/.vim/` on Unix-like systems to customise your experience. There is no real limit to the scope of plugins so you have everything from very small plugins that do a single thing to huge ones that do a lot.

   You can find plugins [at the official site](https://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php) or at [vimawesome](https://vimawesome.com/). Most of them come with instructions.
2. Plugin managers are plugins that make it easier and cleaner to manage plugins. The whole plugin business was more of an afterthought than anything so the "traditional" way of managing plugins could become very manual and messy so some kind of plugin manager was often needed.

   You can find plugin managers at the places mentioned above. They all ahve extensive instructions.
3. "Distributions" (they don't really have an official name), are collections of plugins and configuration files that purport to give users a "full" experience without having to go through the customisation process. They usually contain a plugin manager and a curated list of plugins.

   You can probably find them with the help of your favourite search engine.

---

Now, *the talk*…

As you "just entered this world, and everything it's just confusing", I would recommend you set all of the above aside and only concern yourself with learning Vim properly.

1. If you didn't already, do `$ vimtutor` as many times as needed to get the basics right.
2. As instructed at the end of vimtutor, level up to the user manual `:help user-manual`. It will guide you progressively through *every* feature, from basic to advanced. Go at your own pace, skip chapters, come back to them later, and, most importantly, experiment along the way.
3. Keep an eye on anti-patterns and inefficient actions, find improvements, practice. Rinse. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

What plugin managers do is really simple that you can do it on your own. Typically, it downloads a plugin and then adds it to vim `runtimepath`. As a result, the plugin is enabled when you start Vim next time.

For example, let's say you want to install a plugin such as `https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim`

- Download it, `git clone https://github.com/nanotech/jellybeans.vim`
- In your vimrc, add `set runtimepath+=/path/to/jellybeans.vim`
- Restart vim and now you can use it by `color jellybeans`

Things become complicated if there are a bunch of plugins to add/update/remove or you prefer a gui-like interaction. That's where plugin managers stand out.